# How can I validate an enum in FluentValidator C#

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am creating a validation class using `FluentValidation` in C#, to validate that my `Type` property of `Account` class is of type `AccountType` enum.

What would be the correct implementation of this:

```
RuleFor (account => account.Type)
             .IsInEnum (....)
```

Answer (score 3):

I asked myself the same thing, then I googled it and found your question here.
That didn't help very much. It did however make me go looked at the source and unit tests on github so thanks for that.  https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/master/src/FluentValidation.Tests/EnumValidatorTests.cs

I'm putting this here for the next person that comes along with the same question. You do not need to provide any implementation to the IsInEnum() function. This function uses reflection to determine the Enum type of the property specified in your rule, and then validates the value of that property based on valid values of the Enum.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
public static bool IsDefinedInEnum(this Enum value, Type enumType)
{
    if (value.GetType() != enumType)
        return false;

    return Enum.IsDefined(enumType, value);
}
```

The code can use some explanation:

- The first check simply makes sure that the value of the enumeration and the type of the enumeration are the same. If they are not, the method must return, obviously, `false`. But why is this necessary? `Enum.IsDefined` would cover this too, right?

  Ideally, we'd want a method with the following signature: `IsDefinedIn<T>(this T value) where T: Enum`. This would be totally type safe at compile time but, sadly, the constraint `T: Enum` is not valid. This means that `enumType` can be anything, like `typeof(object)`, there is no mechanism in  the language to constraint `enumType` to only enumeration types. This can make `Enum.IsDefined` throw, if you don't want this happening, you should keep the first check.

  Do consider that you *should* throw (or assert) if passing some type that is not an `Enum` is a bug in your code. I've just shown you how you could get around this issue if necessary.
- The second check simply makes sure the value is defined in the enumeration. `SomeEnumeration.SomeValue` would return `true` and `(SomeEnumeration)5` would return `false` unless there is a member of the enumeration with that value.